# How can I best generate/load a thumbnail

Tags: php, ios, xcode

I'm building a iPhone Application which displays some photos. First in a UICollectionView as a thumbnail then bigger in fullscreen.

For better loading behavior I would like to load smaller images first for the thumbnail part. Now: Should I do this via PHP and resize the existing big image or should I save a second image on the server XXX_thumbnail.png and load this one?

Thanks for your tip.

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resizing an image can be quite an intensive process for the server, especially with larger images. Imagine if 1000 users hit it at the same time. You **absolutely should only do this once per image**, and save it for later requests. Whether you pre-render all thumbnails or not is another matter, but executing a `file_exists` is pretty cheap. You can just render them once, at the time they are requested. All depends how you want to access them (e.g. through a script or just the thumbnail url directly)

Comment: Exact answer to my question! Thanks!